# How to abort HTTP transaction

Tags: java, http, networking

`Browser ----> Http Proxy ----> Web server`

Assume for a request, the web server has indicated that it would send 200 bytes as response body using Content-Length header. The network is broken after 100 bytes and there is eventually a read time-out on the socket from Proxy to Web server.

Design considerations for the proxy

1. Is it okay for the Proxy to close the Http transaction with the Browser after 100 bytes when it should have sent 200 bytes?
2. If you suggest that the Http transaction between Proxy and Browser should be aborted, how do you achieve it?

Comment: i have updated the description of the question. the question is more about what should the proxy do?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Servlet container, I would think the container would handle this internally with an Exception, or, if you have grabbed an OutputStream/InputStream from the HttpServletResponse/HttpServletRequest you would get an IOException writing/reading from the stream.

If you are trying to handle this on your own, using plain Java sockets, then you would get an IOException on the stream since you couldn't write any bytes to it.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the entire 200 bytes will get written to the socket send buffer after the headers and the sender will close the socket without noticing anything has gone wrong at all. At worst the sender will get an IOException: 'connection reset', which the servlet container will catch and ignore.